# Row titles in UITableView Grouped style

Tags: iphone, uitableview

What command do you use in UITableViewController to get the row titles below (mobile, work, birthday, etc.)?  I've been looking everywhere for a specific instance or method, and I can't seem to find it.  Is there extra formatting required, and can it be done without a xib?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz5pP.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

row titles? Do you mean "mobile", "work" and so on? These titles are the textLabel objects when you use `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` as style for your tableViewCell

```
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text = @"mobile";
cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"(888) 555-5512";
```